# how can I refer to an object of another class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a method in one of my classes to be used throughout the project and the propose is to show an alert.

I can create the alert in every class and use the below code overtime:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

If am right `this` refers to the current class object

how can I refer to the object of the class that is invoking the alert method? so that I use the above code only once and invoke it from different classes

Answer (score 2):

You would typically put this code in a method which has a Context object as a parameter, then refer to that parameter by name instead of 'this'.

```
public class Dialogs {

    public AlertDialog createAlert(Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        //etc...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass context as method parameter or for later use you can pass `Context` in constructor, and keep reference in that class and use whenever you want.

```
public class MyClass {

  Context context;

  public MyClass(Context context){
    this.context=context;
  }


  public void createDialog(){

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  }
}
```

or direct calling from contextual(having context) class

```
public void createDialog(Context context){

   AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
}
```